# Golang and HTML5 / CSS / JavaScript (ANDROID apps)

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, go

Is there a way to integrate golang and HTML5 / Javascript to create mobile apps? 
I was going through

> https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/app 
>   https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile

It seems that only OpenGL can be used currently for UI.
I am new to android app development, but for hybrid apps a chrome instance is launched using java, which renders the HTML pages and runs the JavaScript. 
Is there a similar way to achieve the same using Golang ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GopherJS](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs) transpiler from Golang to JS and [goco](https://github.com/jaracil/goco).

Answer (score 0):

gobind it possible to call Go functions from Java and Objective-C.
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind

You can write a plugin for cordova. It can call Go functions.

Cordova can help you to build hybrid app with HTML5/JavaScript.